# Custom column for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-field-types

I want to create a new field type for SharePoint 2013.
It should be for the large lookup list, in edit or new form it'll be represented by a combobox with jQuery for selecting choices.

Do you have a sample on how to do this in Visual Studio?
Will I be able to customize the list display for the custom field?

I have tried [this solution](http://autocompletelookupsp2013.codeplex.com/releases/view/115667) from CodePlex but it is showing following error when I am typing anything in textbox:

[image]

Comment: I think you should avoid custom field type as you can achieve this using JSLink feature available in SharePoint 2013. and if still want to go with farm solution in you can use https://autocompletelookupsp2013.codeplex.com/releases/view/115667

Comment: it's exactly what i need but i deployed it in SP2013 and have an alert when start typing search. i put a printscreen of the error

Comment: can you deploy it from visual studio and can get exact line where it is throwing exception by debugging the code?

Comment: thanks for your help, the error occus in AutocompleteControl.ascx  in error function. RequestedUrl is equal at: http://myssite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/produit()$filter=startwith(ID,'produ')&$select=ID,id

Comment: i did a mistake when creating my column, i linked to id in place of Title.

Comment: sorry i did a mistake when creating my column. i linked to ID in place of Title

Comment: Awesome :) Now you can post your explanation as answer so in future nobody will do that mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was when i created column.
After selecting your list lookup you have to select the field where you want searching.
In my case i had a list with an id and title.
So i select title like this when you'll start to write something it'll search in this column.